# Silverlight DataStateBehavior, initial value not used

Tags: silverlight, triggers, behavior, vsm

I am trying to use the Silverlight DataStateBehavior, it works fine in most cases where I click a button which sets say a 'Selected' Property in the view model to either false or true. The DataStateBehavior then tells the VisualStateManager to go to the relevant state.

Like this:

```
   <Button...>
   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
             <id:DataStateBehavior Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="True" TrueState="SelectedVisualState" FalseState="DeselectedVisualState"/>
          </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
   </Button>
```

The above works fine. What I am trying to do though is to get it to set the correct state when the application loads, if I were to set the 'Selected' property on the view model to true by default I wouldn't see any changes in the UI until I clicked the button to change the viewmodel property.

I know there are several classes involved with the DataState stuff including:

- BindingListener.cs
- ConverterHelper.cs
- DataStateBehavior.cs
- DataStateSwitchBehavior.cs
- DataTrigger.cs

Any clues would be good, 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm actually going to add a second answer which I just tried, and seems to be cleaner since it can be done all in XAML and without a custom behavior. I'll leave the other answer just as a reference for an alternative solution since they both work.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <ic:GoToStateAction StateName="SelectedVisualState"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

You will just need at add a reference to the Microsoft.Expression.Interactions assembly that is part of the Blend SDK.

```
xmlns:ic="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I forgot to mention this would be inside a datatemplate and so the state chosen is dependent on an ID value of the data item for example. If the ID is 0 use state "Open", if the ID is 1 use state "Closed" etc. The above is still really useful, thanks again

Comment: What happens if you change the default/initial values of your data to indicate that you need another state? You now have to update the XAML and your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this extension of the DataStateBehavior class. When the target element loads, the DataStateBehavior will be evaluate as if the property has been updated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace Gusdor.Wpf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Fix for data state behavior. Behavior will trigger transitions when target element loads.
    /// </summary>
    class DataStateBehaviorFix: Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core.DataStateBehavior
    {
        public bool UseTransitionsOnLoad { get; set; }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();

            AssociatedObject.Loaded -= AssociatedObject_Loaded;
        }

        void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Evaluate();
        }

        void Evaluate()
        {
            if (Value == null)
            {
                GotoState(Binding == null, this.AssociatedObject);
            }
            else GotoState(Value.Equals(Binding), this.AssociatedObject);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to change to the named state. Walks up tree to first match.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="flag"></param>
        /// <param name="element"></param>
        void GotoState(bool flag, FrameworkElement element)
        {          
            string stateName = flag ? TrueState : FalseState;

            if (HasState(element, stateName))
            {
                bool ret = System.Windows.VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(element, stateName, UseTransitionsOnLoad);
            }
            else if (element.Parent as FrameworkElement != null)
                GotoState(flag, element.Parent as FrameworkElement);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if an element has the state named
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="element"></param>
        /// <param name="stateName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        bool HasState(FrameworkElement element, string stateName)
        {
            var groups = Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.VisualStateUtilities.GetVisualStateGroups(element).Cast<VisualStateGroup>();

            return groups.Any(p => p.States.Cast<VisualState>().Any(s => s.Name == stateName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably meant to do `-=` in `OnDetaching`

Comment: To get the appropriate behavior it is necessary to add some sort of type conversion to the Evaluate() function. Value.Equals() isn't good enough for XAML string values like "True" or "15". Found this article about XAML type conversion: http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/02/convert-in-code-as-in-xaml-how-to-get-thet-xaml-processors-converter/. I'm about to examine and implement it.

Comment: This solution uses Microsofts recommended approach for object equality. i.e, calling Object.Equals(object). The base data state behavior doesn't treat "True" as true either. Good shout though!

Answer (score 1):

One way I have solved this problem is to make a behavior you can add to your control to put it into an initial visual state upon loading. Here is a simple example:

```
public class InitialVisualStateBehavior : Behavior<Control>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InitialStateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "InitialState",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(InitialVisualStateBehavior),
        null);

    public string InitialState
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(InitialStateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InitialStateProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        if (this.AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_Loaded);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        if (this.AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.Loaded -= AssociatedObject_Loaded;
        }
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this.AssociatedObject, this.InitialState, false);
    }
}
```

You would then just add that behavior to the UserControl-level in XAML:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <myi:InitialVisualStateBehavior InitialState="SelectedVisualState" />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

You could also easily modify this to accept a comma separated list of initial states which you could then split and loop through if you needed to put the control in a bunch of different mutually exclusive states after loading.

This might also be refactored into a TriggerAction that you could just trigger off of the Loaded event of the control, I'm not sure which way would be cleaner.